# Problematic interaction between fontspec and beamer?

Tags: fonts, beamer, polyglossia

There seems to be some problem in the way fontspec passes font info to beamer. The following example compiles and displays as it it should in XeLaTeX

```
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\begin{document}

This is a test.

Это тест
\end{document}
```

However, if I replace the document class with

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
```

I get the error

> ! Package polyglossia Error: 
>   The current roman font does not contain the Cyrillic script!
>   Please define \cyrillicfont with \newfontfamily.
>
> See the polyglossia package documentation for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>    ...
>
> l.3 \select@language {russian}
>
> ?

I compile with MiKTeX 2.9, with all current updates.
Any suggestions would be very appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`beamer` uses the `sffamily` by default, so you need to define the `\cyryllicfontsf` using `\newfontfamily`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{STIX}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfontsf}{XITS}

\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\begin{document}

This is a test.

Это тест
\end{document}
```

(I have the actual STIX fonts installed, so I haven't tested this with XITS but it should work the same.)

If you want to use a sans serif font, then Herbert's solution is the correct one.  I assumed you wanted to make the default Beamer font to use XITS.

Comment: Very good, thank you. I also have MiKTeX's Stix package installed, but for some reason it fails to compile. XITS version works fine, though

Answer (score 5):

define also the sans serif font:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}% or any other sans serif font
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\begin{document}

This is a test.

Это тест

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is closer to what I had in mind. I would like to use XITS in the math, as better-looking alternative to Computer Modern, and keep the rest of the text somehow close in style to the formulas.

Comment: Thank you!  I've thought that it's a bug in Polyglossia or Beamer and they can't be used together until your post.  I've added `\setsansfont{Arial}` and everything got worked!