# Inner theme doesn't work in Russian

Tags: beamer

I'm using a template, almost the same for Russian and English presentation. English one works fine, while in Russian innertheme

```
 \useinnertheme{circles}
```

breaks rendering:

```
! Improper `at' size (0.0pt), replaced by 10pt.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.3 ...mer@sectionintoc {1}{Раздел}{2}{0}{1}
```

Here's a full MWE:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,professionalfont]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage{fontspec} % enagles loading of OpenType fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text} % without this XeLaTeX won't turn "--" into dashes
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

% Russian/English document:
\usepackage{xecyr}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{DejaVu Sans}

\setmainlanguage[numerals=cyrillic]{russian} % \setdefaultlanguage{russian} is obsolete and not needed
\setotherlanguage[variant=american]{english}


% beamer:
\useinnertheme{circles}
% \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\blacktriangleright}
% \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\smblksquare}
% \setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{\smblkcircle}

% toc:
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Обзор}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}


 \frame{
  \frametitle{Структура доклада}
  \tableofcontents[
  pausesections,
  ]
}

\section{Раздел}

\frame{
  \frametitle{Слайд!}
  Текст!
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need `\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfontsf}{DejaVu Sans}` see: [Problematic interaction between fontspec and beamer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34964/5239)

Comment: I marked this question as duplicated.